# count length of lookup field in Dynamics crm

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, crm, fetchxml

I created a fetchxml to filter a contract lookup field in a CRM. I want to be able to see how many records is there in the contract lookup field. If there is only one record I want to be able to auto populate that lookup field.

Tried using an API function to be able to loop through the fetchxml records but not having any luck with returning the count. Is there another way to go about getting the results I need?

```js
 function buildCustomView() {
        // Some GUID but only needs to be unique among the other available views for the lookup
        var viewId = "{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001}";
        var viewDisplayName = "Contracts for This Account";

        //Only need Contracts for the selected Worksite and buisness unit if filled in
        var worksite = getFieldValue("hc_worksite");

        if (!worksite) { return; }
        if (!worksite[0]) { return; }
        if (!worksite[0].id) { return; }
        //check if buisness unit is availble and if it is can filter lookup further
        var buisnessUnit = getFieldValue("hc_businessunit");
        var condition;
        if (buisnessUnit != null) {
            condition = "<filter type='and'>" +
                                  "<condition attribute='hc_businessunit' operator='eq' value='" + buisnessUnit[0].id + "' />" +
                                "</filter>";
            ///if take out the account name, contract lookup will still be filteredl
        } else {
            condition = "";
        }

        //Get all Contracts that pertain to the selected worksite
        var fetchXml = "<fetch version='1.0' output-format='xml-platform' mapping='logical' distinct='true'  >" +
                         "<entity name='contract'>" +
                            "<attribute name='title' />" +
                            "<attribute name='customerid' />" +
                            "<attribute name='contractid' />" +
                            "<attribute name='hc_contracttype' />" +
                            "<attribute name='hc_contractsubtype' />" +
                            "<attribute name='activeon' />" +
                            "<attribute name='hc_contractlevel' />" +
                            "<attribute name='expireson' />" +
                            "<attribute name='hc_contractaccount' />" +
                            "<attribute name='hc_contract' />" +
                            "<order attribute='title' descending='false' />" + condition +
                            "<link-entity name='hc_account_contract' from='contractid' to='contractid' visible='false' intersect='true'>" +
                              "<link-entity name='account' from='accountid' to='accountid' alias='ab'>" +
                                "<filter type='and'>" +
                                  "<condition attribute='accountid' operator='eq' value='" + worksite[0].id + "' />" +
                                "</filter>" +
                              "</link-entity>" +
                            "</link-entity>" +
                          "</entity>" +
                        "</fetch>";
        //Set up the whole view's UI
        var layoutXml = "<grid name='resultset' object='1' jump='hc_contract' select='1' icon='1' preview='2'>" +
                         "<row name='result' id='contractid'>" +
                          "<cell name='title' width='300' />" +
                          "<cell name='hc_contractaccount' width='200' />" +
                          "<cell name='hc_contracttype' width='100' />" +
                          "<cell name='hc_contractsubtype' width='100' />" +
                          "<cell name='hc_contractlevel' width='100' />" +
                          "<cell name='activeon' width='100' />" +
                          "<cell name='expireson' width='100' />" +
                          "<cell name='customerid' width='150' />" +
                          "<cell name='hc_contract' width='100' />" +
                         "</row>" +
                        "</grid>";

        try {
            //Set the view
            Xrm.Page.getControl("hc_contract").addCustomView(viewId, "contract", viewDisplayName, fetchXml, layoutXml, true);
        } catch (e) {
            Xrm.Utility.alertDialog("Error: " + e.message);
        }
        var count = 0;
        //count results of fetch xml
         SDK.WEBAPI.executeFetchSync("contract", fetchXml,
            function (results) {
                
               for (i=0;i<results.length; i++){
                    count++;
                }
                Xrm.Utility.alertDialog(count);
            },
            function (error) {
                //Show error
                alertDialog("Error: " + error.message);
            });
        
    }
```

Comment: you can try aggregate methods supported by fetchxml - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309565.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You can count the records returned by a FetchXML query using the **count aggregate** attribute. See [documentation here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309565.aspx#Anchor_3).

Put `aggregate='true'` in the first line of your fetch:

```
<fetch version='1.0' output-format='xml-platform' mapping='logical' distinct='true' aggregate='true'>
```

And then add a count aggregate attribute:

```
<attribute name='contractid' alias='contract_count' aggregate='count' />
```

Then get the value in your `executeFetchSync` success callback:

```js
results.entities[0].contract_count;
```